# how to set threshold to scikit learn random forest model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

After seeing the precision_recall_curve, if I want to set threshold = 0.4, how to implement 0.4 into my random forest model (binary classification),  for any probability <0.4, label it as 0, for any >=0.4, label it as 1.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
  random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, oob_score=True, random_state=12)
  random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
  predicted = random_forest.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
```

Documentation [Precision recall](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming you are doing binary classification, it's quite easy:

```
threshold = 0.4

predicted_proba = random_forest.predict_proba(X_test)
predicted = (predicted_proba [:,1] >= threshold).astype('int')

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
```

Comment: Hi Stev, my last part give me a error "ValueError: Can't handle mix of binary and multilabel-indicator."    
        accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
    print(round(accuracy,4,)*100, "%")  Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @BigData,Ooops my bad, I didn't run the rest of your code. In that case, you only need to take the second column. That column is 1 if class 1 and 0 if not, which my implication is class 0. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)

threshold = 0.4

predicted = random_forest.predict_proba(X_test)
predicted[:,0] = (predicted[:,0] < threshold).astype('int')
predicted[:,1] = (predicted[:,1] >= threshold).astype('int')


accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
print(round(accuracy,4,)*100, "%")
```

this comes with an error refers to the last accuracy part" ValueError: Can't handle mix of binary and multilabel-indicator"

Answer (score 0):

**sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score** takes 1 d array but your **predicted** array is 2-d. This comes with an error.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

Comment: Instead of using `predicted`, pick the predicted class you want to view the `accuracy_score` for. Use one of `predicted[:,0]` or `predicted[:,1]`, instead of `predicted`.