# Custom function in make_scorer in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, scoring

I am trying to create a custom scoring function to implement into GridSearchCV for a classification problem and don't think I'm quite understanding how it works (I have read the documentation). My goal is to place different weights on the type of misclassifications. My code looks as follows. `good` and `excellent` are two of the classes that my samples fall into. I think the problem is when `GridSearchCV` passes the true and predicted values to `score_func` but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
def score_func(y, y_pred):
    '''score function for grid search'''
    error = 0
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i] == 'excellent':
            if y_pred[i] == 'excellent':
                error += 10
            elif y_pred[i] == 'good':
                error += 5
    return error

score_f = make_scorer(score_func, needs_proba=False ,needs_threshold=False)

RF = make_pipeline(
        StandardScaler(),
        RandomForestClassifier(random_state=101, criterion = 'gini')
        )

gs_rf = GridSearchCV(estimator=RF, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=score_f, 
                     cv=KFold(5, True, random_state=1234)).fit(X_data,y_data)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is `make_scorer()` defined?

Comment: `make_scorer` is not a function, it's a metric imported from sklearn. Check it [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html).

Comment: Right, its a metric in sklearn.metrics in which I should be able to define and implement my own score function [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to associate weights for your labels, you don't need to create a function.

Just use the `class_weight` parameter from `RandomForestClassifier`.

```
weight_dict = {'excellent':10, 'good':5}
RandomForestClassifier(random_state=101, criterion='gini', class_weight=weight_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks! Although say for example I have 3 classes, 'excellent', 'good' and 'poor'. And I wish to say that misclassifying an `excellent` sample as `good` isn't as severe as misclassifying an `excellent` sample as `poor`, could I do this using `class_weight`?

My thinking is that If I defined a score function as above, I could say `error += 0` is the model misclassified the sample as `poor`. That way I could quantify the difference in misclassifications.

Comment: I'll just make a small research about it and give feedback for your here.

Comment: Hi there. I just found this [link](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/thresholding). It's saying that you can define a threshold for each class probability, instead of weights for the classes. Just read it and try to define the decision threshold. Please come back here to say if it worked or not.

Comment: [This other questin in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785904/how-to-set-threshold-to-scikit-learn-random-forest-model) also may helps you.

Comment: Perfect I will look into it now! Thanks for your help!